# Testing whether two number fields are isomorphic

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, computational-number-theory

Could somebody point me to an implementation of an algorithm that takes two number fields $F$ and $L$, tests whether they are isomorphics, and if they are, returns an isomorphism?

There is such a function in MAGMA, called IsIsomorphic, but I'm having a bit of trouble finding the source code. Sorry if this question is not appropriate for StackExchange, I wasn't sure where to ask.

Comment: See things like [this](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00863108/document). Sage and Pari/gp are open source.

Comment: Thanks, that looks helpful. I should say that I have access to MAGMA, but I'm having trouble locating the source code for the function IsIsomorphic, as there are 30+ functions with that name.

Comment: Did you look at https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/217 http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/monaganm/teaching/TopicsinCA17/TragerFactor.pdf